# Determining if a set of polynomials is a Gröbner basis for the ideal generated by those polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that the question may sound obvious to most of you, but for some reason I have encountered a mental block with this. So suppose that we have a set of polynomials, $A = \{x^3 + x, x^2 + x\}$ and we were asked whether or not $A$ is a Gröbner basis for $\langle A \rangle$. Well, for $A$ to be a Gröbner basis for $\langle A \rangle$ would mean that any $f \in \langle A \rangle$ is divisible by $A$, i.e. we can iterate the division process with elements in $A$ until the remainder is zero. Well the form of $f$ is $f = h_1(x^3 + x) + h_2(x^2 + x)$ for polynomials $h_1, h_2$. Therefore does it not mean that $f$ is automatically divisible by $A$, i.e. $A$ is a Gröbner basis for $\langle A \rangle$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Gröbner basis $G$ for an ideal $I$ you have the property that $f\in I$ if and only if the division of $f$ into $G$ is 0.

Let $G$ be just a generating set of $I$. If the division of $f$ into $G$ is 0, $f$ will lie in $I$. The converse does not hold.

As a note, in a polynomial ring $K[x]$ all ideals are principal.

Comment: So because for example $x^3 + x - x(x^2 + x) = x - x^2$ and as $x$ is not divisible by any of the highest terms of either $x^3 + x$ or $x^2 + x$, the set $A$ is not a Gröbner basis for $\langle A \rangle$?

Comment: In your example, Singular tells that $\{x\}$ is the reduced Groebner basis.

Comment: Okay, but does that mean that my reasoning was correct about $A$ not being the Gröbner basis? I am a novice in algebra, so it is best if you'd imagine talking to a child or a golden retriever.